# Unable to Send parameter In HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

i need to send a data to server using multipart i have successfully sending image  to server using **HttpURLConnection** Multipart image is loading successfully but i am sending id also but id is not sending to server. so can you help me where is error .i

```
public String uploadData() {
        String fileName = mRealProfilePicPath;

        // Log.e("mrealpath",fileName);
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(mRealProfilePicPath);

        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            // URL url = new URL("http://stank.cwsdev3.biz/text.php/");
            // URL url = new
            // URL(AppUtills.BASE_URL+"user/update_profile?&dump=1");
            URL url = new URL(AppUtills.BASE_URL + "user/update_profile?");
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("profilepic", fileName);
            conn.setRequestProperty("first_name", firstName);
            // conn.setRequestProperty("dump","1");
            // conn.setRequestProperty("id",
            // AppPreference.getUserId(con,AppUtills.USERID));

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            String param1 = AppPreference.getUserId(con, AppUtills.USERID);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"id\""
                    + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + param1.length() + lineEnd);  // unable to upload this
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(param1 + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profilepic\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd); // image uploading

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage
                    + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("TAG, POST Response Code :: ", "" + responseCode);

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                Log.i("TAG", response.toString());
                return response.toString();

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "no";

    }
```

Comment: You've stepped through the code to see for sure that there is a value inputted at  **AppPreference.getUserId(con, AppUtills.USERID)**

Comment: yes i have check its right , even here i have also checked using hard code

Comment: Then it's a problem at your web server.

Comment: according to you code is right

Comment: If you're getting a value, then I think your code is correct.